# Twitter API - saving OAuth token in session

Tags: session, oauth, twitter

I am trying to find a way to keep connected with the Twitter API once authorised using OAuth but am having problems.

I get `"Invalid / expired Token"` when trying to connect to Twitter API using a saved Oauth token in a session or database.

Is there a way to do this?  I dont want the users of my App to have to login via Twitter every time.  Surely once they have authorised my App once, that should be enough?

```
$consumer_key = 'consumerkey';
$consumer_secret = 'consumersecret';

$twitterObj = new EpiTwitter($consumer_key, $consumer_secret);

if (isset($_GET['oauth_token'])){
    $oauth_token = $_GET['oauth_token'];
} else if ($_SESSION['oauth_token']){
    $oauth_token = $_SESSION['oauth_token'];

    echo $_SESSION['oauth_token'];
} else {
    //see if authorisation already set up in DB
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT oauth_token FROM PingSocialMediaUsers WHERE oauth_provider = 'twitter' AND clientID = '$clientID'");  
    $result = mysql_fetch_row($query); 
    $oauth_token = $result[0];
}

if($oauth_token == ''){ 
    $url = $twitterObj->getAuthorizationUrl();
    $twitter_login = $url;
 } else {
    $twitterObj->setToken($oauth_token);
    $token = $twitterObj->getAccessToken();
    $twitterObj->setToken($token->oauth_token, $token->oauth_token_secret);     
    $_SESSION['oauth_token'] = $token->oauth_token;
    $_SESSION['oauth_secret'] = $token->oauth_token_secret;
    $twitterInfo= $twitterObj->get_accountVerify_credentials();
    $twitterInfo->response;

    echo $twitterInfo->response['error'];
    //echo '<pre>';
    //print_r($twitterInfo);
    $id = $twitterInfo->id;
    $username = $twitterInfo->screen_name;

    //add to details database
    //find the user by ID  
    if ($id != ''){
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM PingSocialMediaUsers WHERE oauth_provider = 'twitter' AND oauth_uid = '$id'");  
        $result = mysql_fetch_array($query);  

        // If does not exist add to database  
        if(empty($result)){  
            $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO PingSocialMediaUsers (oauth_provider, oauth_uid, username, oauth_token, oauth_secret) VALUES ('twitter', {$id}, '{$username}', '{$_SESSION['oauth_token']}', '{$_SESSION['oauth_secret']}')"); 
            $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM PingSocialMediaUsers WHERE id = " . mysql_insert_id());  
            $result = mysql_fetch_array($query);  
        } else {  
            //update the tokens  
            $query = mysql_query("UPDATE PingSocialMediaUsers SET oauth_token = '{$_SESSION['oauth_token']}', oauth_secret = '{$_SESSION['oauth_secret']}' WHERE oauth_provider = 'twitter' AND oauth_uid = {$id}");  
        }   

        $_SESSION['id'] = $result['id']; 
        $_SESSION['username'] = $result['username']; 
        $_SESSION['oauth_uid'] = $result['oauth_uid']; 
        $_SESSION['oauth_provider'] = $result['oauth_provider']; 
        $_SESSION['oauth_token'] = $result['oauth_token']; 
        $_SESSION['oauth_secret'] = $result['oauth_secret'];    
    }

    $twitterAuth = TRUE;    
}
```

Comment: Your access token should be valid until revoked by the end user him/herself. How do you store them? Sure they are identical to the ones received from twitter, sure you have the right token secret?

Comment: I have tried storing it in both a session and a database but whichever way, I get the error.  The only time it works is when I autorise with Twitter and therefore get the autorisation key from the callback URL using the $_GET method.  I have shown the code above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are talking about `access_token` which you will get from the twitter as last part of OAuth handshaking after which you can go to access there services on user behalf.

Here is what they are saying in there official developer page

```
We do not currently expire access tokens. 
Your access token will be invalid if a user explicitly 
rejects your application from their settings or if a Twitter admin suspends 
your application. If your application is suspended there will be
a note on your application page saying that it has been suspended.
```

So you can very well store that token in your database and can always use at later stage.

here is the reference to there API page
[Twitter OAuth FAQ](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/oauth/faq)

So i suggest you to make sure that you are not changing any application setting and you are getting a valid access_token from session/database

Comment: I have realised it is not allowing me to connect with the access token without the token secret. I therefore also need to save the oauth_token_secret in the database. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @LeeTee i have not integrated with Twitter but with google ,yes you have to pass same secret_token else will always going to get a kick from google :)